# Determining KAP assessment post-intervention significance: use a paired t-test, signed-rank Wilcoxon, or other?

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm newer to statistics and unsure how to analyze my data for a cohort study (n=73) where KAP assessments were administered to the same pregnant women before and after an educational intervention for gestational toxoplasmosis. The attitude/practices sections were scored on a Likert scale of 1-5 --> "never, almost never, sometimes, almost always, and always." I want to show the p-value significance in changes of each attitude question (A1-A5) and each practice question (P1-P7). When I attempt a Wilcoxon signed rank in R, the exact p-value is unable to be computed with both zeroes and ties.

Would anyone be able to aid me in determining which would be better, considering many of the questions the data is left-skewed (primarily to 4s and 5s)?

Example of one of the questions inputted into R -- I'm stuck in terms of how to improve/condense what I have to yield p values from the data. Would anyone be able to aid me in this?

````
print(paste("P7"))
pre_intervention <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)



post_intervention <-c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)

# Perform paired t-test
result_ttest <- t.test(pre_intervention, post_intervention, paired = TRUE)

# Extract the p-value
p_value <- result_ttest$p.value

# Print the p-value
print(p_value)

# Perform Wilcoxon signed-rank test
result_wilcox <- wilcox.test(pre_intervention, post_intervention, paired = TRUE)

# Extract the p-value
p_value <- result_wilcox$p.value

# Print the p-value
print(p_value)
```
````

Comment: Just to be clear, is your question about how to code this or how to interpret the results? Coding questions are better left for Stack Overflow, whereas statistical questions are better suited here.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Moreso a stats question selecting the appropriate type of test for the nonparametric conditions despite the sample size -- but coding as well if possible, which I'll ask on Stack Overflow (thanks, this is relatively new to me)